# why is my localeresolver printing the localecode instead of the content?

Tags: java, localization

When I want to display an internationalized message from the properties files the webpage displays `??headline_en??` instead. Does anyone know what is causing this? This is my properties file.

```
headline = Welcome to my Site
intro = this is my english intro
```

And these are the required beans I use for localization:

```
    @Bean //https://phraseapp.com/blog/posts/how-to-localize-spring-applications-like-a-pro/
public LocaleResolver localeResolver(){
    SessionLocaleResolver sessionLocaleResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
    sessionLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
    return sessionLocaleResolver;
}

@Bean
public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor(){
    LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
    return localeChangeInterceptor;
}

@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource(){
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource =
                new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("language");
    messageSource.setCacheSeconds(10);
    return messageSource;
}

    @Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry){
    registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
}
```

Is the reloadablemessagesource to blame somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this solved my problem

```
        resourceBundleMessageSource.setBasename("classpath:language");
```